# How to align buttons in Shoes GUI Toolkit in Ruby

Tags: css, ruby, shoes, green-shoes

I am creating a GUI application using Shoes toolkit in Ruby, and using `require 'green_shoes'` gem.

project is in progress but i had a problem to align buttons to center
does anyone know about how to?
i have an example code:

```
Shoes.app width:500, height: 400 do
     stack do
          para "input here"
          button button1
          @content = edit_line
     end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use: left, right, top, and bottom. I am not sure about centering, but you can give x,y coordinates in pixels.

```
stack(left: 35, top: 90) do
      para "input here"
      button button1
      @content = edit_line
 end
```

This is also a good walkthrough: http://shoesrb.com/walkthrough/